# How to get setting values from word files, and save them to an array?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am a VBA noob and I am working on a script that would capture the header and footer settings of all word files in a folder. I would like to create an array, and save the values for header and footer for each file that can be found on the folder. I think I have managed to create the loop, however, I do not know how to save these values to an array.

Here is a sample of my script:

```
Option Explicit
Public savepath As String

'This will select the file/folder
Public Sub select_folder()

Dim Filepicker As FileDialog
Dim mypath As String

Set Filepicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    
    With Filepicker
        .Title = "Select folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        .ButtonName = "Select(&S)"
            If .Show = -1 Then
                mypath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
            Else
                End
            End If
    End With
NextCode:
    'select_folder = mypath
    Set Filepicker = Nothing
    savepath = mypath

End Sub

Sub excel_report()

Dim strFile As String
Dim strInFold As String
Dim extension As String
Dim WrdSrc As Word.document
Dim WrdApp As Word.Application
  'count the files in the folder
    strInFold = savepath
    extension = "*.doc*"
    strFile = Dir(strInFold & extension)

 Do While strFile <> ""
 counter = counter + 1
 strFile = Dir
 Loop
 Dim arry(counter, 3) As Variant
 
 'save values of files into an array
    strInFold = savepath
    extension = "*.doc*"
    strFile = Dir(strInFold & extension)

Do While strFile <> ""
'open word application
        On Error Resume Next
    ' Check whether Word is running
    Set WrdApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If WrdApp Is Nothing Then
        ' Word is not running, create new instance
        Set WrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        ' For automation to work, Word must be visible
        WrdApp.Visible = True
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
DoEvents
' open file
Set WrdSrc = WrdApp.Documents.Open(filename:=strInFold & strFile)

'Add Array (arry) Values here

'assign strfile (file name) on column 1
'WrdSrc.Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range on column 2
'WrdSrc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range on column 3

'move to next row

Loop

End Sub
```

I am trying to achive an output that looks like this:

```
FileName        HeaderValue        FooterValue
testfile.doc    ABCD Company       Confidential Information
Testfile2.doc   CDEF Company       All rights reserved to CDEF company
```

And I would like to add this array to a new sheet, then add this sheet to the current workbook where this vba script is running.

How do we go about doing this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The process is rather more complex than you envisage: every Section in a Word document can have up to three headers and three footers - primary, first page, and even page. Hence a 10-Section document could have as many as 30 of each. Moreover, headers and footers might contain tables, textboxes, pictures, page numbering fields, StyleRef fields, etc., as well as text spanning multiple paragraphs - all of which can be difficult to get into a single Excel cell.

Comment: For code that shows how to loop through all headers & footers in multiple documents, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/62942-post2.html. Although that code is for applying new headers/footers, the looping through documents, Sections, headers and footers remains the same. All you need do is capture the data and figure out how you're going to arrange it in Excel. I'll also leave it to you to decide whether you want to automate Word from Excel or Excel from Word - I'd do the former.